# How to implement Queryable state in corda?

Tags: corda

I had a offer state which is implementing LinearState and It was working fine till this point. Then I needed to implement Queryable state in our Offer state But when I implement the Queryable state and implement the schema for persistent state and When I run the flow it is not doing anything and flow is terminating without showing any error. When I approched the logs of the node, an exception was there which is as follows:

```
stack (net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:101) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CompatibleFieldSerializer.write(CompatibleFieldSerializer.java:65) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:575) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.io.serialization.kryo.ReplaceableObjectKryo.writeObject(ReplaceableObjectKryo.java:85) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:79) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CompatibleFieldSerializer.write(CompatibleFieldSerializer.java:65) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:575) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.io.serialization.kryo.ReplaceableObjectKryo.writeObject(ReplaceableObjectKryo.java:85) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:79) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CompatibleFieldSerializer.write(CompatibleFieldSerializer.java:65) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:575) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.io.serialization.kryo.ReplaceableObjectKryo.writeObject(ReplaceableObjectKryo.java:85) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:79) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CompatibleFieldSerializer.write(CompatibleFieldSerializer.java:65) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:575) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.io.serialization.kryo.ReplaceableObjectKryo.writeClassAndObject(ReplaceableObjectKryo.java:54) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultArraySerializers$ObjectArraySerializer.write(DefaultArraySerializers.java:361) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultArraySerializers$ObjectArraySerializer.write(DefaultArraySerializers.java:302) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:575) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.io.serialization.kryo.ReplaceableObjectKryo.writeObject(ReplaceableObjectKryo.java:85) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:79) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CompatibleFieldSerializer.write(CompatibleFieldSerializer.java:65) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObjectOrNull(Kryo.java:629) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:86) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:508) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber$FiberSerializer.write(Fiber.java:2109) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber$FiberSerializer.write(Fiber.java:2086) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:575) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.io.serialization.kryo.ReplaceableObjectKryo.writeObject(ReplaceableObjectKryo.java:85) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:79) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CompatibleFieldSerializer.write(CompatibleFieldSerializer.java:65) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:575) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.io.serialization.kryo.ReplaceableObjectKryo.writeObject(ReplaceableObjectKryo.java:85) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:79) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CompatibleFieldSerializer.write(CompatibleFieldSerializer.java:65) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:575) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.io.serialization.kryo.ReplaceableObjectKryo.writeObject(ReplaceableObjectKryo.java:85) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:79) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CompatibleFieldSerializer.write(CompatibleFieldSerializer.java:65) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:575) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.io.serialization.kryo.ReplaceableObjectKryo.writeClassAndObject(ReplaceableObjectKryo.java:54) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:100) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:40) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:575) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.io.serialization.kryo.ReplaceableObjectKryo.writeObject(ReplaceableObjectKryo.java:85) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:79) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CompatibleFieldSerializer.write(CompatibleFieldSerializer.java:65) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObjectOrNull(Kryo.java:629) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:86) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CompatibleFieldSerializer.write(CompatibleFieldSerializer.java:65) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:575) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.io.serialization.kryo.ReplaceableObjectKryo.writeClassAndObject(ReplaceableObjectKryo.java:54) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultArraySerializers$ObjectArraySerializer.write(DefaultArraySerializers.java:361) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultArraySerializers$ObjectArraySerializer.write(DefaultArraySerializers.java:302) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:575) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.io.serialization.kryo.ReplaceableObjectKryo.writeObject(ReplaceableObjectKryo.java:85) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:79) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CompatibleFieldSerializer.write(CompatibleFieldSerializer.java:65) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObjectOrNull(Kryo.java:629) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:86) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:508) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber$FiberSerializer.write(Fiber.java:2109) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber$FiberSerializer.write(Fiber.java:2086) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:575) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.io.serialization.kryo.ReplaceableObjectKryo.writeClassAndObject(ReplaceableObjectKryo.java:54) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.KryoCheckpointSerializer$serialize$1$1.invoke(KryoCheckpointSerializer.kt:116) ~[corda-node-api-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.KryoCheckpointSerializer$serialize$1$1.invoke(KryoCheckpointSerializer.kt:42) ~[corda-node-api-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.KryoStreams$kryoOutput$1.invoke(KryoStreams.kt:30) ~[corda-node-api-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.KryoStreams$kryoOutput$1.invoke(KryoStreams.kt) ~[corda-node-api-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.serialization.internal.ByteBufferStreams.byteArrayOutput(ByteBufferStreams.kt:22) ~[corda-serialization-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.KryoStreams.kryoOutput(KryoStreams.kt:26) ~[corda-node-api-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.KryoCheckpointSerializer$serialize$1.invoke(KryoCheckpointSerializer.kt:107) ~[corda-node-api-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.KryoCheckpointSerializer$serialize$1.invoke(KryoCheckpointSerializer.kt:42) ~[corda-node-api-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.KryoCheckpointSerializer$kryo$1.execute(KryoCheckpointSerializer.kt:70) ~[corda-node-api-4.5.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.pool.KryoPoolQueueImpl.run(KryoPoolQueueImpl.java:58) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.KryoCheckpointSerializer.kryo(KryoCheckpointSerializer.kt:66) ~[corda-node-api-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.KryoCheckpointSerializer.serialize(KryoCheckpointSerializer.kt:106) ~[corda-node-api-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.serialization.internal.CheckpointSerializationAPIKt.checkpointSerialize(CheckpointSerializationAPI.kt:130) ~[corda-core-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl$suspend$1.write(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:484) ~[corda-node-4.5.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber$3.run(Fiber.java:1994) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:824) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) ~[quasar-core-0.7.12_r3-jdk8.jar:0.7.12_r3]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:63) ~[corda-node-4.5.jar:?]
**Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence, which is a closeable resource, has been detected during flow checkpointing. Restoring such resources across node restarts is not supported. Make sure code accessing it is confined to a private method or the reference is nulled out.**
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.AutoCloseableSerialisationDetector.write(KryoCheckpointSerializer.kt:36) ~[corda-node-api-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.AutoCloseableSerialisationDetector.write(KryoCheckpointSerializer.kt:31) ~[corda-node-api-4.5.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObjectOrNull(Kryo.java:629) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:86) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    ... 89 more
```

I have made the line bold which I think defines the problem mostly.

Here is the code for the state.

```
@BelongsToContract(OfferContract.class)
public class OfferState implements LinearState, QueryableState {
    private final UniqueIdentifier linearID;
    private AnonymousParty sender;
    private AnonymousParty receiver;
    private final String policyID;
    private final double faceValue;
    private double offeredAmount;
    @Nullable
    private boolean isActive;


    public OfferState(UniqueIdentifier linearID, AnonymousParty sender, AnonymousParty receiver, String policyID, double faceValue, double offeredAmount, boolean isActive) {
        this.linearID = linearID;
        this.sender = sender;
        this.receiver = receiver;
        this.policyID = policyID;
        this.faceValue = faceValue;
        this.offeredAmount = offeredAmount;
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }

    public AnonymousParty getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    public AnonymousParty getReceiver() {
        return receiver;
    }

    public double getOfferedAmount() {
        return offeredAmount;
    }

    public String getPolicyID() {
        return policyID;
    }

    public double getFaceValue() {
        return faceValue;
    }

    public UniqueIdentifier getLinearID() {
        return linearID;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public List<AbstractParty> getParticipants() {
        return Arrays.asList(sender,receiver);
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public UniqueIdentifier getLinearId() {
        return linearID;
    }


    @Override
    public PersistentState generateMappedObject(@NotNull MappedSchema schema) {
        if (schema instanceof BeLifeSchemaV1) {
            return new BeLifeSchemaV1.PersistentOffer(
                    this.sender.toString(),
                    this.receiver.toString(),
                    this.policyID,
                    this.faceValue,
                    this.offeredAmount,
                    this.linearID
                    );
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unrecognised schema $schema");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<MappedSchema> supportedSchemas() {
        return  Arrays.asList(new BeLifeSchemaV1());
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("OfferState(LinearID = %s, Sender = %s, receiver =%s, policyID = %s, faceValue = %.2f, offeredAmount = %.2f)",linearID,
                sender.getClass().getName(),receiver.getClass().getName(),policyID,faceValue,offeredAmount );
    }
}
```

This is the code for my schema

```
package com.template.Schema;

/**
 * The family of schemas for IOUState.
 */
public class BeLifeSchema {}
```

And here is the code for SchemaV1

```
public class BeLifeSchemaV1 extends MappedSchema {
    public BeLifeSchemaV1() {
        super(BeLifeSchema.class, 1, Arrays.asList(PersistentOffer.class));
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getMigrationResource() {
        return "BeLife.changelog-master";
    }

    /**
     * An OfferState schema.
     */
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Offer_states")
    public static class PersistentOffer extends PersistentState {
        @Column(name = "sender") private final String sender;
        @Column(name = "receiver") private final String receiver;
        @Column(name = "policyID") private final String policyID;
        @Column(name = "faceValue") private final double faceValue;
        @Column(name = "offeredAmount") private final double offeredAmount;
        @Column(name = "linear_id") @Type (type = "uuid-char") private final UniqueIdentifier linearId;


        public PersistentOffer(String sender, String receiver, String policyID, double faceValue, double offeredAmount, UniqueIdentifier linearId) {
            this.sender = sender;
            this.receiver = receiver;
            this.policyID = policyID;
            this.faceValue = faceValue;
            this.offeredAmount = offeredAmount;
            this.linearId = linearId;
        }

        // Default constructor required by hibernate.
        public PersistentOffer() {
            this.policyID = null;
            this.offeredAmount = 0;
            this.sender = null;
            this.receiver = null;
            this.faceValue = 0;
            this.linearId = null;
        }

        public String getSender() {
            return sender;
        }

        public String getReceiver() {
            return receiver;
        }

        public String getPolicyID() {
            return policyID;
        }

        public double getFaceValue() {
            return faceValue;
        }

        public double getOfferedAmount() {
            return offeredAmount;
        }

        public UniqueIdentifier getLinearId() {
            return linearId;
        }
    }
}
```

I could not find any solution for this till now.

Please see If anyone can help. I am stuck here for days now.

Comment: Please share the code of your Schema and SchemaV1.

Comment: Schema Code added.

Answer (score 0):

As Adel said, without your schema it's hard to know what could be causing this.

Separately the error is actually mentioned in that log here:

`**Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence, which is a closeable resource, has been detected during flow checkpointing. Restoring such resources across node restarts is not supported. Make sure code accessing it is confined to a private method or the reference is nulled out.**`

That being said the last thing I can share is some examples of queryableState being implemented. R3 maintains some samples.

In this IOUState sample the class implements both LinearState and QueryableState.

https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/master/Basic/cordapp-example/contracts-java/src/main/java/com/example/state/IOUState.java

There's also this sample using QueryableState for a Car insurance use case.

https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/master/Features/queryablestate-carinsurance/contracts/src/main/java/net/corda/examples/carinsurance/states/InsuranceState.java

good luck!

Comment: Thanks, Davidawad, I have tried looking into the examples already but I could not identify the mistake. I have updated the question by adding the schema code into it. Please see, If you can catch the point of error.